# initializing Byte array with malloc is problematic?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a struct type, MESGB with details:

```
typedef unsigned char Byte; 
typedef struct MESGB 
{ 
unsigned int soh; 
unsigned int stx; 
unsigned int etx; 
Byte checksum; 
Byte msgno; 
Byte *data; 
} MESGB;
```

and I have a variable named frameBuf, which is array of MESGB:

```
#define buffSize 6
#define maxElmt 3
static MESGB frameBuf[buffSize]
```

when I want to Initialize frameBuf with this function:

```
int k;
for(k = 0; k<=buffSize-1; k++)
{
    frameBuf[k].soh = SOH;
    frameBuf[k].stx = STX;
    frameBuf[k].etx = ETX;
    frameBuf[k].checksum = 0;
    frameBuf[k].msgno = -1;
    frameBuf[k].data = (Byte*) malloc (maxElmt*sizeof(Byte));               
}
```

what I found strange is that, if I write a value to frameBuf data like this:

```
frameBuf[0].data[0] = 'a'
frameBuf[0].data[1] = 'b'    
frameBuf[0].data[2] = 'c'
frameBuf[1].data[0] = 'd'
frameBuf[1].data[1] = 'e'    
frameBuf[1].data[2] = 'f'
frameBuf[2].data[0] = 'g'
frameBuf[2].data[1] = 'h'    
frameBuf[2].data[2] = 'i'
```

when I try to print all of frameBuf data, I get the output like this:

```
frameBuf[0].data[0] = 'g'
frameBuf[0].data[1] = 'b'    
frameBuf[0].data[2] = 'c'
frameBuf[1].data[0] = 'g'
frameBuf[1].data[1] = 'e'    
frameBuf[1].data[2] = 'f'
frameBuf[2].data[0] = 'g'
frameBuf[2].data[1] = 'h'    
frameBuf[2].data[2] = 'i'
```

and I came to conclusion that if I change the value of frameBuf[i].data[0], all of other frameBuf[j].data[0] will change too, which I found disturbing. Even though if I change the data in data[k] where k is other integer in 0, it will not change any other data[k] in other frameBuf[]

Can somebody explain to me how to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance! :D

[Edited]: 
you can see the code in: http://ideone.com/6BRsU
I initialize frameBuf in initFrameBuf, 
assign data to frameBuf in transMessage, 
and the strange output is in retryTransWindow

[Edited]:
Solved. Okay, the problem is not in array initializing. 
All of it is my clumsiness in coding.
Thanks for all of your's help! ^^

Comment: you need to show how you assign the `.data` field.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect `maxElmt` is not what you think it is.

I get this output:

```
frameBuf[0].data[0]='a'
frameBuf[0].data[1]='b'
frameBuf[0].data[2]='c'

frameBuf[1].data[0]='d'
frameBuf[1].data[1]='e'
frameBuf[1].data[2]='f'

frameBuf[2].data[0]='g'
frameBuf[2].data[1]='h'
frameBuf[2].data[2]='i'

frameBuf[3].data[0]='j'
frameBuf[3].data[1]='k'
frameBuf[3].data[2]='l'

frameBuf[4].data[0]='m'
frameBuf[4].data[1]='n'
frameBuf[4].data[2]='o'

frameBuf[5].data[0]='p'
frameBuf[5].data[1]='q'
frameBuf[5].data[2]='r'
```

...using this code:

```
typedef unsigned char Byte;

typedef struct MESGB_T
{
    unsigned int soh;
    unsigned int stx;
    unsigned int etx;
    Byte checksum;
    Byte msgno;
    Byte *data;
} MESGB;

#define buffSize 6
#define maxElmt 3

static MESGB frameBuf[buffSize];

Byte curChar = 97;

void Init()
{
    int k, i;
    for(k = 0; k<=buffSize-1; k++)
    {
        frameBuf[k].soh = 23; // SOH;
        frameBuf[k].stx = 24; // STX;
        frameBuf[k].etx = 25; //ETX;
        frameBuf[k].checksum = 0;
        frameBuf[k].msgno = -1;
        frameBuf[k].data = (Byte*) malloc (maxElmt*sizeof(Byte));
        for (i=0; i < maxElmt; i++)
        {
            frameBuf[k].data[i]=curChar++;
        }
    }
}

void Print()
{
    int k, i;
    for(k = 0; k<=buffSize-1; k++)
    {
        for (i=0; i < maxElmt; i++)
        {
            printf("frameBuf[%d].data[%d]='%c'\n",
                   k,i, frameBuf[k].data[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Init();
    Print();
}
```

Comment: It must be at least 3, otherwise you will run into problems assigning `framebuf[k].data[2]`. (You will write into memory that has not been allocated)

Comment: Yes, you can use any expression in `malloc` but you need a bigger `maxElmt`

Comment: when I saw your code, I dont see any difference with mine when initializing frameBuf, but why do I get different output? Actually, the code that I post above is not exactly the same code when I got this problem, It's much complex. I'll do some more analyzing then, maybe the problem is somewhere else. Thanks for your help! :D

Comment: That's how pointer errors manifest themselves. It could be that you are stomping on `.data` and the pointer to the malloc'd space is lost. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Is `maxElmt` large enough (in particular, is it >=4)?

Did you try to compile your program with all warnings and debug enabled `-Wall -g` (assume a `gcc` compatible compiler), to improve it till you got no more warnings, and to debug it using a debugger (like `gdb`)?

Comment: no, maxElmt is 3, and when I change it into 4, the output is becoming more strange: the problematic index in data is now 0 and 1, not just 0

Comment: What is the type of `Byte`. I think everyone is assuming its unsigned char, but maybe you have something else? Or just a bug in your assignment or output code. Maybe you could post your code (or at least part which exibits the problem), either here or on http://ideone.com

Comment: oh yes, sorry I didnt put that: typedef unsigned char Byte;